# Do i need to convert a sessionvariable to string?

Tags: vb.net, variables, session-variables

.

```
Session("UserName") = "Sally"  
Dim userName As String = Session("UserName")
```

Do i need to convert the session variable to string if i wanna follow "good coding practices"?

Ex:

```
Session("UserName") = "Sally"  
Dim userName As String = Convert.ToString(Session("UserName"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as a good practice and if you want to assign to a new variable:

```
Dim userName As String = Session("UserName")
```

Otherwise you can use it directly:

```
Print Session("UserName")
```

Note that value `"Sally"` (wrapped in quotes) is a string.

Comment: I was assigning the sessionvariable to a new string variable in my question?! And yes "Sally" is a string and it should be a string when assigning it to the session variable.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should be using

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
```

at all times, it makes the compiler yell at you when you cast implicitly or use undeclared identifiers.

Comment: Yes i have the strict and explicit mode on all the time! :)

Comment: If that's the case, then the compiler will warn you when you assign to a string variable from an object. String is a reference type though, so you still have to check for null / Nothing yourself.